# Yii 404 error with urlmanager showscript to false

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

i am finalizing my work on Yii application and I want to have prettier URLs. I went through googling over sites and Yii wiki and went according the manuals. However, I am stuck at the point of being unable to hide index.php form my URL. With index.php in my url it works, the site opens, without it, it gices me server 404.

This is my main.config:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
 'urlFormat'=>'path',
 'showScriptName'=>false,
 'rules'=>array(
   '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
   '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
 ),
),
```

With 'showScriptName' set to false I get 404.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

I am currently testing the site on localhost using WAMP. Mod_rewrite on Apache is running. Changed http.conf to Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Allow Override All.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

For those struggling! Put the .htaccess to the root of your application, not inside the protected folder!!!

Comment: I know this is an old answer. But could you please explain more detail about this? Because this is works for me but I have no idea what make it works. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
'' => 'site/index'
```

to your urlManager 'rules' array.
The logic is, Yii can't match the request of pattern `''` with any of your defined rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'urlSuffix' => '.html',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            //  'caseSensitive'=>false, 
            'rules' => array(
                 '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
   '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

In your .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Upload your htaccess in project folder.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, using your same settings this two scenaries occurs:

1. https://somedomain.com/action123   [Fail, stupid 404]
2. https://somedomain.com/action123/  [success]

problem is, the final "/" symbol (more rules needed)